# Not able to read Tag value using libplctag.NET

Tags: c#, plc

I am working on using C# to retrieve tag value from AB PLC. I used the open source library below for my development.
https://github.com/libplctag/libplctag.NET

Image below is the configuration that I am using in PLC tag. Meanwhile, the source code below is the one I used for ready the selective tag. When I run the code, it show error at the line of "myTag.Write()". I purposely hide the write code line and just tested on read, but it doesn't return the actual tag reading.

Can anyone advise what is the mistake that I had did from the code?

[AB Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf4vi.png)

```
            //A simple starting example that demonstrates reading and writing a DINT tag

            //Instantiate the tag with the proper mapper and datatype
            var myTag = new Tag<DintPlcMapper, int>()
            {
                Name = "PROGRAM:DataLOG_Test.TestDINT",
                Gateway = "192.168.236.20",
                Path = "1,0",
                PlcType = PlcType.ControlLogix,
                Protocol = Protocol.ab_eip,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
            };

            //Initialize the tag to set up structures and prepare for read/write
            //This is optional as an optimization before using the tag
            //If omitted, the tag will initialize on the first Read() or Write()
            myTag.Initialize();

            //The value is held locally and only synchronized on Read() or Write()
            myTag.Value = 3737;

            //Transfer Value to PLC
            myTag.Write();

            //Transfer from PLC to Value
            myTag.Read();

            //Write to console
            int myDint = myTag.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(myDint);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code worked with my PLC.

```
var myTag = new Tag<DintPlcMapper, int>() {
Name = "TIME_CONSTANT",
Gateway = "192.168.1.1",
Path = "1,0",
PlcType = PlcType.ControlLogix,
Protocol = Protocol.ab_eip,
Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};
```